# How to convert PKCS#8 with password to PKCS#1 with JCE

Tags: certificate, rsa, pkcs#1, pkcs#8

I have a .pem file(PKCS#8) which has below sections in same file

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

xx
xx

-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

xx
xx

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

It is protected with passcode/password.

How can I decrypt this in java to PKCS#1 within JDK/JCE without BouncyCastle. I cannot even use the openssl commands.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Why errors do you get when you use the openssl command-line? What do you mean by "decrypt this to PKCS#1"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.